# How to run RDC Windows application

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, ui-automation

I tried lot in running RDC windows application on there I'm trying to capture details.

Like ---- > connecting Myremotedesktop ----> Run the windows application in rdc and enter values to get details *(eg if I enter rollnumber address details will come)* ----> capture details data and store it on my local desktop.

Is there any way to automate this process using c# code?

I'm able to connect remote desktop.
I tried the UIAutomation and the below code working fine for local desktop:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.RootElement;
            Condition appCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Untitled - Notepad");
            Condition documentCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "document");
            AutomationElement documentElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, documentCondition);
            documentElement.SetFocus();
            SendKeys.SendWait("This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.")
```

How to do this same thing on remotedesktop?

Comment: Are you in control of the program running on the server, as in can you make changes to it? There are things you can change on the server program to make it listen for data commands, but you need to write the program to do it.

Comment: I don't have server control...

Comment: Can you put a program on the server that will run with startup (either via the startup menu or by specifying the initial program via the rdp connection file)?

Comment: Hi Scott I need to run the application from another server through local server application(eg Through Code Connect RDC and run the application).

Comment: Yes, I know your control program will be running on the client, my question is are you able to put a custom program and manually/automatically have it start up. You need something server side to listen for the Virtual Channel to issue your automation commands.

Comment: No I'm not able to put a custom program... Is it possible to send keystrokes through scripts.

Comment: I tried like the below code Process rdcProcess = new Process();
            rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmdkey.exe");
            rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/generic:sv/servername /user:" + "Vishnus" + " /pass:" + "Vis123!@#Oma";
            rdcProcess.Start();

            rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
            rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v " + "servername";            rdcProcess.Start();

Answer (score 0):

Due to your requirement of not being able to put any software on the server side of the RDP connection remote control like you want to do is impossible unless the buttons you want to click are int he same position every time and you hard code the X,Y values of where to move the mouse in your automation script.

If you could run something on the RDP server you could take your automation code and write a listener program that would talk to your client over [Virtual Channels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which would allow you to pass messages to your listener over the RDP connection and the listener could perform the automation tasks server side.

Answer (score 0):

Can you force the client side to be Windows 8?  I believe that UI Automation requests get "tunneled" through the RDC connection on Windows 8.